# transfer one form input data to another form

Tags: php

I am trying to transfer option value from one form to another form. Basically I have two forms and I want transfer input data from one form to another form  by $_post method.

Here is my form 1 **search.php**,

I am trying to transfer selected value of this form to another form.

`echo $_post['name ']` working for input type text but when

I am trying to get option data then nothing  found.

```
<form action="<?php echo get_page_link(2229) ?>" method="POST" >
    <input  type="text" name="city_location" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="start typing here....">
    <select name="sleeps">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit_btn" class="button">
</form>
```

This is my second page **list.php** where I want to show selected data of form 1

```
<form method="post" id="sidebar_sform" action="">
    <select name="city_location" class="full-width" id="s_country" data-live-search="true" value="<?php echo $_POST['city_location'];?>">
        <option value="">Any</option>
        <?php  print_r(mad_get_towns_list());?>
    </select>
    <select name="sleeps" value="<?php echo $_POST['sleeps[0]'];?>">
        <option value="<?php echo  $_POST['sleeps[0]'];?>" disabled="" selected="">Sleeps</option>
        <option value="<?php echo  $_POST['sleeps[0]'];?>">1</option>
        <option value="<?php echo  $_POST['sleeps[0]'];?>">2</option>
        <option value="<?php echo  $_POST['sleeps[0]'];?>">3</option> 
        <option value="<?php echo  $_POST['sleeps[0]'];?>">4</option>
        <option value="<?php echo  $_POST['sleeps[0]'];?>">5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit_btn" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: It won't work like this. Create the options and for each one of them, have a conditional inside and echo "selected" if the value from POST is the same value as the option.

Comment: Phiter@please can you provide me solution . it will be helpful for  me.

Comment: You need to learn `HTML` and properties of [`Select`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Comment: GYaN @I will be laern can you help me right now regarding this ,I tried all

Answer (score 1):

Well Gyan, phiter Thanks .I solved this , this is solution of my own question .
Thanks  for support this is working .

```
<?php

(isset($_POST["sleeps"])) ? $sleeps = $_POST["sleeps"] : $sleeps=1;

?>                                      
<select id="company" name="sleeps">
 <option value="" disabled="" selected=""></option>
<option <?php if ($sleeps == 1 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="1">1</option>
<option <?php if ($sleeps == 2 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="2">2</option>
<option <?php if ($sleeps == 3 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="3">3</option>
<option <?php if ($sleeps == 4 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="4">4</option>
<option <?php if ($sleeps == 5 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="4">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Good... I am going to answer your question... But you learnt this by yourself... I appreciate this... Upvoted....

Comment: GYaN@thanks , this was difficult for me ,its only possible for your help